# Why can't I use "->" with "this" and "[ ]"?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I'm playing around with composition, and in one of my classes I have a wrapper around the subscript operator "[ ]" (from std::vector). However, the compiler (g++) gets mad when I say `this->[i]`. I've worked around this issue by using `(*this)[i]` instead, but I thought these were synonyms. What am I missing? Here is a small sample code that throws the error (I'm purposely avoiding iterators in `newmethod` just to simply illustrate my problem).

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class A {
  private:
    std::vector<int> rep;
  public:
    std::size_t size() { return rep.size(); }
    int& operator[](std::size_t index) { return rep[index]; }
    void newmethod();

    A(size_t n, int m) : rep(n,m) {}
};

void A::newmethod() {
  for (std::size_t i=0; i < (this->size()); ++i) {
    std::cout << (*this)[i] << " ";
  }
  for (std::size_t i=0; i < (this->size()); ++i) {
    std::cout << this->[i]; << " "; //Causes an error!
  }
  return;
}

int main() {
  A(17,3).newmethod();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to call the `operator[]` member function directly, something like:

```
this->operator[](i)
```

Answer (score 2):

`a->b` is equivalent to `(*a).b`. What exactly do you expect to happen when you say `a->[b]` and it translates to `(*a).[b]`?

Answer (score 2):

That is not correct, if we look at the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) we can see that `E1->E2` is equivalent to `(*(E1)).E2` and not `(*E1)E2`, this is covered in section `5.2.5` *Class member access* paragraph *2*:

> [...]The expression E1->E2 is converted to the equivalent form (*(E1)).E2;[...]

so what follows `->` has to be a member of the class(*or a base class*), so in this case that would be `operator[]`:

```
this->operator[](i)
```